# (PHP) SWF Autoplay Issue

Tags: php, flash

I have tried many variations of this but I haven't found a resolution.

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="983" height="77">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.ekonomigazete.com/bant.swf&autoStart=true" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <embed src="http://www.ekonomigazete.com/bant.swf" quality="high" wmode="opaque" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="983" height="72"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: It would help to know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: The problem is swf is not autoplayed at index page , i was searching for how to activate to autoplay swf

Comment: Removing chatter and correcting grammar

Comment: @BoğaçhanFuruncu... is `http://www.ekonomigazete.com` your website or you are just loading **from** it as source to your own different website? If you are **getting from** then it's assumed to be some advert and these days advert banners will not auto-play in most browsers.